Salvage Washer Motor
I’m trying to salvage the motor of a WFW96HEAC Whirlpool washing machine.
It has three wires: black, brown, & white.
When I attach any two wires directly to a 120v electric line, the motor shakes and hums.
Do I need to use a lower voltage? What instrument would do that?

What instrument would do that? ... do what?

get the washing machine service manual... it should contain a wiring diagram

A quick Google search says that it is a direct drive motor with a motor controller, so chances are you will need that motor controller too.

Looks like it's a 3-phase BLDC motor. The OEM controller is shown here. You might be able to substitute a commercial VFD for the OEM controller, but they are fairly complex devices.

Here you will find a video from someone who managed to reverse engineer the protocol of a similar motor controller and get the controller to respond to commands. He has put the data up on his github. If the particular one is not the same yours it should act as a guide to how to figure out the commands. It may not be possible to easily figure out things like status codes etc. returned by the motor controller, but basic commands should not be that difficult in today's world of inexpensive logic analyzers.
Note that the one in the video was confirmed as opto-isolated so that it was (relatively) safe to connect to it. Connecting to a non-isolated circuit with a computer could lead to electrical shock and/or destruction of the computer and motor driver.

The few I've taken apart where wound for about 80 V to allow a 100-240 V single phase input VFD (three phase output) to drive it. The heater would be 100/120/230 V specific but allowed the manufacturer to use the same of everything else.

I have the OEM controller as pictured above. Is there a way to supply electricity to that controller to get it to rotate the motor?

I would imagine it communicates with a controller for the cycle timing and user displays by some means, possibly a bidirectional serial link, but figuring that out might take some effort. Not to mention possible issues with mains isolation.

Here is a link to the electric design: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1142662/Whirlpool-Wfw94hex.html?page=84#manual

You are going to need either a capacitor (aka a "run" capacitor) hooked up to the unused lead to create a virtual phase for the motor. Or, a centrifugal switch that opens after a certain RPM are reached (likely still in your washing machine). Check the motor name plate for clues. Or, post the part number of the motor. It's best you understand the motor in better detail before you just willy nilly hook appliances up to the mains.

It may be a single-phase, capacitor-run motor, wired as shown below.

